# JavaFX setup is not working, because of environment variables possibly

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, javafx

I will be using `JavaFX` on a project. I am no expert but I did install it once with no major issue or problem.

But I switched to a new computer and after trying to install it doesn't build; at first I got the message that

`JavaFX runtime` components were missing then got the `java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found`

and I did check other posts that had the same error as the mentioned above but got no solution to the problem and now the message is

> `Unrecognized option: --module-path Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.`

(Please note that I'm using VS Code and no build tools, I am referencing the libraries to use JavaFX)

[Path to JavaFX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQNsQ.png)

[launch.json configured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZUzS.png)

[JRE path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0sYW.png)

[Environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUX5b.png)

And I'm really confused with the JRE, SDK and JDK, I installed the SDK using VS Code but I don't know if my environment variables are configured as they should be...

Thanks in advance for the help, since I'm no expert I don't know if this information is enough, I hope it is :)

Comment: no screenshots of plain text please

Comment: If `--module-path` is not recognized, then that means you're using Java 8 or older. Modules were added in Java 9. I see you have a JDK 17.0.3 in your `Path` variable, but the entry immediately before it is pointing to a Java 8 installation (the `...\Oracle\Java\javapath` entry). Since that entry is first, it takes precedence. Also, your `JAVA_HOME` variable is pointing to a Java 8 installation.

Comment: @Slaw I just uninstalled Java 8 since I won't be using it. Now i get the `Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found` how do I proceed? I do have the PATH_TO_FX set up too...

Comment: [openjfx.io getting started](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) documents using JavaFX with VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

My suggestion is to use [JavaFX of vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-gui) to build the project instead of JavaFX SDK.

I think the main problem is still caused by the environmental settings.

If you must use the JavaFX SDK, put it in a location without spaces, or quote the path when using it. And please read the [document](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij) in detail.